# java : Identifier expected error when calling a void method from another class

Tags: java

So I've been trying to create a set of cards by defining them through their value then create one class per color. I have a method for creating a list of 13 cards from 2 to ace:

```
package test;

import java.util.*;

public class Cartes { 

    void liste_cartes(){    

        ArrayList liste_cartes = new ArrayList();       

        for(int i=2; i<15; i++) {        
            liste_cartes.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using this method in my color class !

```
package test;

import java.util.*;

public class Coeur {    
    Cartes cartes = new Cartes();    
    cartes.liste_cartes();    
}
```

However I'm getting an `<identifier expected>` error on `cartes.liste_cartes();`. Relatively new to Java here, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Statements need to be inside a method.

Comment: try this: `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { Cartes cartes = new Cartes(); cartes.liste_cartes();}`

Comment: Try it with `ArrayList<Cartes> liste_cartes = new ArrayList();` You need to specify what you want to store in the ArrayList.

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker not necessary, although you generally should.

Comment: Don't use raw types! `List` and its subtypes require a generic parameter, in your case `List<Integer> cartes = new ArrayList<>();`. I took the liberty of changing your names to follow the naming conventions, and changing the name of the collection reference not to be the same as the method's.

Comment: statements need to be in a method,also you have to create the entry signature dish `public static void main(String[] args)` if your only using a normal application and not a JApplet

Answer (score 1):

For Java program,JVM first looks for main() to run the program. Try writing this:-

```
public class Coeur {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cartes cartes = new Cartes();
    cartes.liste_cartes();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `cartes.liste_cartes();` in a method, like

```
public void dummyMethod(){ //should probably be your main method, if in your main class
    cartes.liste_cartes();
}
```

Also, your `ArrayList` is of raw type. Make use of generics.

```
ArrayList<Integer> liste_cartes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```